# What's the Spanish expression for 'In a nutshell'?

Tags: traducción, modismos, comparación-de-idiomas

Is there a translation that means something similar as it does in English?

In my case I need that this was in the Informatic Sciences field, you can see the expression in this book: [Java in a Nutshell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596007736)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two phrases that come to my mind to translate "In a nutshell":

- En resumidas cuentas
- Compendio

I think the second one can be used better for your example, in the following form:

> Compendio de Java

See here the definition in RAE for "Compendio":

> **[compendio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A0MqpFs)**
>
> Del lat. compendium.
>
> 1. m. Breve y sumaria exposición, oral o escrita, de lo más sustancial de una materia ya expuesta latamente.
> 2. m. El Salv. complicación (‖ dificultad).
>
> en compendio
>
> 1. loc. adv. p. us. en sustancia (‖ en resumen).

Answer (score 5):

Like always, idiomatic expressions cannot be translated directly and saying *"Java en una cáscara de nuez"* wouldn't make any sense. Instead, we have to go to the meaning of it and try to find some equivalents.

Since the expression refers to "knowledge to be gained through a not very long set of information", these are the expressions that I would use in Spanish:

- En resumen
- En pocas palabras

Or even:

- Guía rápida de Java
- Breviario de Java

Comment: "In a nutshell" isn't quite the same as "through not a very long set of information." It's more like "The general shape of", or "the most important parts."

Comment: As a matter of fact, there *is* at least one literary instance of such a direct translation, by a prestigious publishing house: Stephen Hawking's [The universe in a nutshell](http://www.casadellibro.com/libro-el-universo-en-una-cascara-de-nuez/9788408131281/2330809).

Comment: @Flimzy interesting! Not being an English native speaker I wasn't sure. So would "breviario" or "guía  rápida" make sense?

Comment: @guillem uhms, doesn't it look like a too direct translation? As if we were saying "turkey's mocus" or ["from lost to the river"](http://www.fromlosttotheriver.com/) : )

Comment: @guillem As discussed in [one answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/27003/18899) to the German.SE question that I assume triggered this question, the title of the book comes from a quote from Hamlet that uses "nutshell" in the literal sense.

Comment: "Breviario"? Sorry but I'm a semi-native Spanish speaker (from Spain) and I've never heard this word before. For sure it's not a common Spanish word in Spain nowadays (maybe in some Latin American countries?). Also, there's no definition for this word in the normative Spanish dictionary that really fits this meaning (http://dle.rae.es/?id=65VCqYQ) (the closest one is marked as "obsolete")

Comment: @Pere this is funny, I thought it was used normally. I have books like "Breviario de mitología clásica", so I assumed this is still a valid and common word. Not to be used in conversations, but at least in books.

Comment: "Breviario" in Chile that word isn't used at all. I agree though that the expression "in a nutshell" isn't closest to "en resumen", so I agree with Flimzy point. @guillem, it doesn't matter, it still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @fedorqui out of curiosity if it was me the ignorant, today I conducted a little poll at the office. For half of the desk, it was a known and almost a usual word (one acknowledged having a "Brevario" of something, like you), albeit they agreed it could sound a little old fashioned. The other half, plus me, didn't know it at all... Oh, and maybe the sample size was not significant at all (five people...).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot makes sense, maybe that's the reason that I found only that book, and [one transcription of a lecture by Derrida](http://www.casadellibro.com/libro-la-deconstruccion-en-una-cascara-de-nuez/9789875743595/1655584). I don't know if the lecture had originally an English title (the lecture was in English but at a Spanish university), thought; or whether the editor wanted to nod to Hawking's book.

Comment: Not that I use it in the oral register, but «breviario» does not sound strange to me, either.

Answer (score 3):

"En pocas palabras" (this would be my personal choice) 
"En breve"
"En resumen"
"En esencia"

Google Translate says: "en una palabra"... please don't use this one.